# Split a comma separated string while removing whitespace and empty entries

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, lambda

I wanted to convert a comma-separated string to a string-array and also remove whitespace and empty entries. For example, given the input:

```
string valueString = "sam, mike,   , ,john  , Tom and jerry  , ";
```

The expected result would be the following values (trimmed, of course):

```
sam
mike
john
Tom and Jerry
```

I have tried the following line of code which trims the values, but this fails to remove "empty" entries:

```
valueString.Split(',').Select(sValue => sValue.Trim()).ToArray();
```

What would be the best way to go about trimming the input and cleaning up and empty entries that might result in the process?

Comment: What problem are you having with it? Did you get an error?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Using Trim with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` doesn't work because `"    "` isn't considered an empty entry. You need to do a normal split, then trim each item, then filter out the empty strings.

```
valueString.Split(',')
    .Select(x => x.Trim())
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: it should be `new [] {','}`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: No, it shouldn't (only for strings).

Comment: Any reason you used `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` rather than just `IsNullOrEmpty`?

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer from Anthony, this will convert it back to a comma delimited string as well:

```
valueString = string.Join(",", valueString.Split(',')
    .Select(x => x.Trim())
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
    .ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works on mine....

`item.Split({"|"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: This gives multiple errors since the param is expecting a string array rather {"|"}. Furthermore, it is is not trimming the string as well. Please verify

Comment: Try replacing {"|"} with CChar("|")