# String conversion c#

Tags: linq, lambda

I wanted to format a comma separated string to string with no white spaces, no extra commas  and remove empty entries in c#.

```
string valueString = "sam, mike,   , ,john  , Tom and Jerry  , "
```

and Expected result is string array with trimmed values as below

```
string formattedString = "sam, mike, john, Tom and Jerry"
```

there should be a space after comma (", ") into formatted string

Comment: You already asked this question here [Split a comma separated string also remove white spaces and remove empty entries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662124/split-a-comma-separated-string-also-remove-white-spaces-and-remove-empty-entries) and accepted solution provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string valueString = "sam, mike,   , ,john  , Tom and Jerry  , ";

var nonEmpty = from s in valueString.Split(',')
    where !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)
    select s.Trim();

string formattedString = nonEmpty.Join(", ");

Console.WriteLine(formattedString);
```

Comment: Instead of `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Trim())`, you could use `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.

Comment: You want string.Join(", ", nonEmpty), not join on IEnumerable<string>.

Answer (score 2):

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string s in valueString.Split(new { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    sb.Append(s.Trim());
}
string result = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
string valueString = "sam, mike,   , ,john  , Tom and Jerry  , ";

var strOutput= from s in valueString.Split(',')
                where !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.Trim())
                select s.Trim();

string formatString = string.Join(", ", strOutput);

Console.WriteLine(formatString);
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another variant, now with regex

```
string valueString = "sam, mike,   , ,john  , Tom and Jerry  , ";
string formattedString = (new Regex(@"(\s*)(?<val>[^,]+)(\s*,)?").Replace(valueString,m=>{
            var res = m.Groups["val"].Value.Trim(); 
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(res)? string.Empty : (res+", ");
        })).Trim(", ".ToCharArray());
```